# Burninate the stackapps tag

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

Should we burninate the [stackapps](/questions/tagged/stackapps) tag? It says:

> If you have a question about the API, or an application or script listed there, you should post them on stackapps.com itself, not here.

So let's make it go! API stuff goes to stackapps, bugs in stackapps go there as [bug](https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/bug) in stackapps.

<sub>Oh and don't put [stackapps](/questions/tagged/stackapps) here!</sub>

Comment: Feck it, let's just burn 'em all and have done with. We'll all get more work done  :D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. MSE is the meta for StackApps too, so questions on that site, including the tag, are still very valid and should be kept.

So questions on the actual API go to StackApps. Questions about the working of the site, the design, bugs *on the working of the site* (not the API), etc. go here.

Comment: Then why is there a bug tag there?

Comment: Sorry, not bugs to the API, bugs on the working of the site.